# Определение геопозиции на яндекс карте

Tags: яндекс-карты

Предоставляет ли яндекс возможность определения геопозиции, указав маркер на их карте? Видел эту фишку на авито, стало интересно они сами это делали либо яндекс дает такую возможность? Копался в АПИ их карт, не нашел что тою

Comment: Уточните что именно вас интересует... Есть подозрение что вы говорите об обратном геокодировании (когда по координатам точки определяется адрес), но могу и ошибаться.

Comment: В идеале я так представлял. Выходит карта, на карте можно перетаскивать маркер по каким то объектам, и он определял его координаты.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/25152) и [тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_properties]).

Comment: Делал еще на старой версии АПИ: http://scripts.pws.ru/maps/onepoint.php До сих пор работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно предоставляет. Вот пример как это делается:

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode

Comment: Действительно, спас меня от изобретения велосипеда..